# Server Send Events on GAE: ¿is it possible?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, websocket, streaming

I want to enable some sort of realtime mechanism involving PHP (backend) and JS (frontend). And SSE seemed like a nice approach since I don't require bidirectional connections.

The issue I'm facing is that Google App Engine is buffering the PHP response, breaking flush() usage, hence preventing me from building a SSE server.

Does anyone knows how to make GAE NOT to buffer the response? use streaming?sockets? an alternative that is proven to work under GAE? I've tried using channels but that comes with a great challenge since my application has been built entirely bases in PHP and the only thing that I want is to add some realtime notification functionality. And having 2 languages coexist in the same project has it's own complexity too.

Any answer, suggestion, input or feedback will be most appreciated.

Comment: look at gcm for a free alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As @Shrike pointed out in a comment the information in this answer is outdated. With new runtimes (python3, Java 11, PHP7) you have a request timeout of 10 minutes with automatic scaling and 24 hours with basic or manual scaling (source: [app engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-instances-are-managed)).

Even so it is not possible to use server sent events

> App Engine does not support streaming responses where data is sent in incremental chunks to the client while a request is being processed. All data from your code is collected as described above and sent as a single HTTP response.

(Source: [official google appengine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled#streaming_responses))

**legacy answer (for Java 8, PHP 5 und Python 2):**

Technologies like Server Sent Events and Web Sockets will not work on App Engine by design. All front-end requests in App Engine are limited to a runtime of 60 seconds, tasks to ten minutes. So even if you would leave the connection to the client open (like for Server Sent events) it would be closed after 60 seconds. If you could open a web socket connection to a task (which you can't) it would be closed after ten minutes.

The alternatives are:

- The [Channel API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) as you pointed out yourself. However the channel API does not seem to integrate well with PHP.
- As Zig Mandel pointed out [google cloud messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
- Switching to [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)

Comment: I've meassure the runtime timeout (I've taking GAE to it's limits to know what I an or can't do) and so far I've got 60 secs, not 30. Nonetheless, your input is very insightfull: I have not tried Cloud messaging or VMs.
I think I'll give it a try to GCM. Thanks!

Comment: You're absolutely right. The request deadline is 60 seconds. I'll correct it in my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: this is not correct anymore. Request timeout for automatic scaling - 10 minutes, for basic and manual - 24 hours, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types

Comment: @Shrike thanks. I updated the answer according to the new specs.

Comment: @konqi cool, unfortunately SSE still doesn't work on GAE Standard (only on Flexible)

Comment: @Shrike hmmm I cannot verify that. Technically it should be possible to simply keep the connection open for the duration of 10 minutes. It sure doesn't sound very practical to do so . Can you refer me to your source of information?

Comment: @konqi https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-handled#streaming_responses

Comment: @Shrike cool, thanks - i'll update the answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by disabling buffering which you can do by setting `X-Accel-Buffering: no` in the response header.

> By default, all responses from App Engine are buffered in 64k-blocks. In some cases, it might make sense to disable buffering and directly stream bytes to the client. This is generally preferred when using hanging GETs or Server Sent Events (SSEs). To disable buffering, you can set the X-Accel-Buffering response header to no.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/how-requests-are-handled?tab=node.js#x-accel-buffering